# Does Node.js still support UDP broadcasting?

Tags: node.js, udp, multicast

I called `dgram.setBroadcast(flag)` and it returned a *not yet implemented* error on Node.js version v0.6.3.

Does Node.js still support UDP broadcasting?

*Edit: I found [some discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/c294ead91fde78e2?pli=1) said that broadcast was removed in 0.5.x and probably be back in the future.*

still **not** yet implemented in **v0.6.6**

I tried 0.6.10 in windows 7 x64, the multicast did not work yet.

```
var dgram = require('dgram'); 
var PACKET_LEN = 64; 
var message = new Buffer(PACKET_LEN); 
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4"); 
client.setMulticastTTL(128); 
//dgram.addMembership(multicastAddress, [multicastInterface]) 
client.addMembership('234.18.128.10', "172.18.128.64") ; 
// dgram.send(buf, offset, length, port, address, [callback]) 
client.send(message, 0, PACKET_LEN, 7000, "234.18.128.10"); 
client.close(); 

I got an "Error: addMembership EADDRNOTAVAIL".
```

after ref here: **https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-dgram-multicast-multi-process.js** ,
I finally make multicast work on my windows pc. 

node ver=0.6.19

```
var dgram = require('dgram'); 
var message = new Buffer('this is my message'); 

var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4"); 
client.bind();
client.setBroadcast(true)
client.setMulticastTTL(128); 
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 5007, "224.1.1.1"); 
client.close();
```

Comment: Well in the discussion says that it will be back in v0.6.4 or v0.6.5. Version 0.6.4 is due to 3 days, and probably one more week for 0.6.5.

Answer (score 6):

Today's your lucky day: Datagram support was reintroduced in nodejs 0.6.9.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/01/27/node-v0-6-9/

Comment: And in windows version 0.6.10 I can't send multicast successfully too :-(, although it's changelog said it can.

Comment: To timoxley:

var dgram = require('dgram');
var PACKET_LEN = 64;
var message = new Buffer(PACKET_LEN);
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
client.setMulticastTTL(128);
//dgram.addMembership(multicastAddress, [multicastInterface]) 
client.addMembership('234.18.128.10', "172.18.128.64") ;
// dgram.send(buf, offset, length, port, address, [callback])
client.send(message, 0, PACKET_LEN, 7000, "234.18.128.10");
client.close();

I got an "Error: addMembership EADDRNOTAVAIL".

Comment: sorry for the terrible formatting. I added the code to the question.